# Not able to open pages through navbar getting no page found error

Tags: html, flask

```
<!--navigation bar-->
    <header>
    <nav>  
        <ul>  
        <li><a href="index.html"> About </a></li>  
        <li><a href="home.html"> Home </a> </li>  
        <li><a href="login_register.html">Login/Register </a> </li>  
        <li> <a href="createCloset.html"> Create your closet </a> </li>  
        </ul>  
    </nav>  
    </header>

    <!--app.py-->
     from flask import Flask,render_template
    import os
    prerna = os.path.join('static','pic.png')
    prerna2 = os.path.join('static','Untitled.png')
    prerna3 = os.path.join('static','wardrobe.png')
    video = os.path.join('static','DigitalWardrobe.mp4')
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    @app.route('/index')
    def index():
        return render_template("index.html",img = prerna2,img1 = prerna,img2 = prerna3,vid=video)
    
    @app.route('/home')
    def home() :
        return render_template("home.html")  
    
    if __name__=="__main__":
        app.run(debug=True,port=8000)
```

i have only added route to home and the index page to app.py till now not to other options in navbar and still i m not able to acess even that two pages also.

Answer (score 0):

Mention the route in the anchor tag instead of the filename.

```
<li><a href="/index"> About </a></li>
```

You can also try the `url_for()` method too.

```
<li><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"> About </a></li>
```